# protractor - setting safari options to set window size etc.,

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, safaridriver

like in chromeOptions, where we can set args and prefs, How can we provide `safari.options` to set window size?

i tried the below with protractor 4.5.1/ safari 12.0 in Mac

```
safari: {
    name: 'Safari',
    browserName: 'safari',
    window_size: 'maximize',
    options:{
        cleanSession: true
    }
}
```

but not able to see Safari window maximizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
onPrepare: () => {
    let width = 1920;
    let height = 1080;
    browser.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    // if you wish to maximize it.
    // browser.manage().window().maximize();
}
```